# SQL Server - Only get a single row for each distinct value of a field

Tags: sql, sql-server, distinct

I just got home from a job interview in which they made me take a programming test. One of the questions which really stumped me was as follows:

> You are a teacher at a high school and have been put in charge of picking the best possible debate team for the upcoming National Debate Championships. Given the following table structure:

> ```
> CREATE TABLE CompetitionResults (
>     StudentName NVARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,     -- The student's name
>     SchoolYear INT NOT NULL,                -- The school year of the student at the time they entered the competition
>     CompetitionDate DATE NOT NULL,          -- The date of the competition
>     CompetitionResult INT NOT NULL          -- The student's final score in the competition (0 - 100)
> )
> ```
>
> Write a query that will return the names of the best candidates for the upcoming competition, based on their previous competition results.

> Constraints:
>
> - Return a single column, `StudentName`.
> - Only one student should be picked from each school year (7 - 12).
> - Each returned student must have competed in exactly 3 other competitions this year.

It's the last constraint in particular that I had the most trouble with. Here's what I ended up submitting after running out of time:

```
SELECT
    StudentName AS sn,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) AS NumComps, CompetitionDate FROM CompetitionResults
        WHERE YEAR(CompetitionDate) = 2020 AND NumComps = 3),
    SchoolYear,
    CompetitionDate,
    CompetitionResult
FROM CompetitionResults
WHERE CompetitionDate IN (SELECT MIN(CompetitionDate)
    FROM CompetitionResults GROUP BY CompetitionDate) AND
    CompetitionResult IN (SELECT MAX(CompetitionResult) FROM
    CompetitionResults WHERE StudentName = sn);
```

In the interest of professional growth, I'd love to be able to tackle this problem with as little help as possible, but as you can probably tell, I'm really struggling here. This code won't even compile, let alone the performance implications of all the subqueries! I find them easier to code than joins, however, hence my use of them here.

Any guidance/tips would be very much appreciated. MTIA :-)

Comment: What's wrong with `Count()` and `HAVING`? A `GROUP BY` would help, too. It's also impossible you'll return a single column when your `SELECT` statement contains 5 columns.

Comment: "*It's also impossible you'll return a single column when your SELECT statement contains 5 columns*". I'm well aware of that, but I think that's meant to be part of the challenge. I guess some kind of join or something is needed to drop the extra columns...or maybe I should've made a temp table with all info, and selected from that. I'm really not sure :-/

Comment: @KenWhite, not only it is very much possible but it is also very simple: Nested selects where the outer one returns the sole column you are interested, right?

Comment: @FDavidov: I was referring to the SELECT that the OP provided in the question. I didn't say it was impossible other ways.

Comment: @KenWhite, thanks for your clarification. You may wish to consider rephrasing your comment though. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me, this is basically aggregation . . . with a little bit of window functions:

```
select studentname, SchoolYear, avg_competitionscore
from (select studentname, SchoolYear, avg(competitionscore) as avg_competitionscore,
             row_number() over (partition by SchoolYear order by avg(competitionscore) desc) as seqnum
      from CompetitionResults cr
      where year(CompetitionDate) = year(getdate())
      group by studentname
      having count(*) = 3
     ) s
where seqnum = 1;
```

The subquery is summarizing the competitions for each student, applying the appropriate filtering conditions -- both on the individual competitions and on the overall number.  The outer query chooses one per year.

I don't see how exactly three competitions has anything to do with the best.  I suspect that the part about choosing the *best* students based on scores is a "hidden requirement" used to distinguish between merely acceptable solutions from the best solutions.

I suppose there could be additional logic to check that there is at least one candidate per year, but the question suggests that there is at least one such student.

Comment: NIce! Never come across partitions before, but after reading a bit about them, they seem to make sense. Thanks! +1

Answer (score 0):

I guess this can be solved with Window Functions. Following an example - might need some tweaking after all, but you should get the idea:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(
  StudentName NVARCHAR(255)
 ,SchoolYear INT
 ,CompetitionDate DATE
 ,CompetitionResult INT
)

INSERT INTO @t VALUES
('Peter', 7, '2019-01-01', 100)
,('Peter', 8, '2020-01-01', 100)
,('Peter', 8, '2020-03-01', 100)
,('Paul', 10, '2020-01-01', 100)
,('Paul', 10, '2020-03-01', 100)
,('Paul', 10, '2020-04-01', 100)
,('Mary', 11, '2019-01-01', 100)
,('Mary', 11, '2019-02-01', 100)
,('Mary', 11, '2019-03-01', 100)
,('Jacob', 12, '2020-01-01', 100)
,('Jacob', 12, '2020-02-01', 100)
,('Jacob', 12, '2020-03-01', 100)
,('Jacob', 12, '2020-04-01', 90)
,('Jennifer', 9, '2020-03-01', 100)
,('Jennifer', 9, '2020-04-01', 100)
,('Jennifer', 9, '2020-05-01', 100)
,('Lucas', 12, '2020-03-01', 100)
,('Lucas', 12, '2020-04-01', 100)
,('Lucas', 12, '2020-05-01', 100)

;WITH cte AS(
SELECT *
      ,COUNT(CASE WHEN YEAR(CompetitionDate) = YEAR(GETDATE()) THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) OVER (PARTITION BY StudentName, YEAR(CompetitionDate)) AS CountCompYear
      ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY StudentName ORDER BY CompetitionDate DESC) AS LastCompetition
      
  FROM @t
),
cteFilter AS(
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SchoolYear ORDER BY CompetitionResult DESC, StudentName ASC) AS DistStudent
  FROM cte
  WHERE CountCompYear = 3
    AND LastCompetition = 1
)
SELECT *
  FROM cteFilter
  WHERE DistStudent = 1
```

Comment: Tyron, I don't have access to a DB right now so I'm just commenting without any test of your suggestion. I think you are missing one filter: In your example, for each school year there is one and only one candidate due to the number of competitions they took part of (i.e. "7" none, "8" none, "9" Jennifer, "10" Paul, "11" Mary, "12" Jacob). What would happen if you have two matching people for the same year, one with scores 100, 100, 100 while the other 100,100,99? Perhaps, you should add the AVERAGE computation to properly compare and hence be able to select the best.

Comment: One more thing, the query should also consider the case in which two students have exactly the same average (perhaps including a `TOP 1` somewhere).

Comment: @FDavidov Concerning your first question: Jacob and Lucas are both in year 12. Concerning the TOP 1: this is done by the `ROW_NUMBER` in cteFilter. And last but not least: yeah, average might be a solution. But you said "as little help as possible", so consider this query as a rough draft which needs - as mentioned in my answer - some tweaking. ;)

Comment: Tyron, thanks for your reply. Now, for year 12 I made a mistake in my previous post; the one returned is Lucas since Jacob is disqualified (4 participations instead of 3), As per `ROW_NUMBER`, it would indeed help if you would use along with `ORDER BY` and `TOP 1`, elements I don't see in your example. Last, you are right, your suggestion is a **seed** and the OP should be aware of that; my comments are also for him to consider. Cheers.

Comment: @FDavidov you are right - I changed the query from `>= 3` to `= 3`. Concerning the `ROW_NUMBER` it is defined with `ORDER BY` and `PARTITION BY` and lateron filtered by `... = 1` - so this should be an alternative to `TOP 1` since this would require subqueries etc. (since TOP 1 returns only one row - not per student or year pr whatever but only the first found row).

Comment: Wow...I think you owe me a few brains. I keep losing one everytime I look at your code and it explodes :P. I think it's safe to say I won't be hearing from them ever again LOL.

Comment: @Kenny83 everything before `;with cte` is just sample data. In the first cte the `COUNT` is for younting the competitionf in the current year per student. The `ROW_NUMBER` in this cte provides numbers per student in descending order by CompetitionDate. `cteFilter` filters on the required "exactly 3 competitions" and on the last competition per student and provides the numbering per SchoolYear ("only one student per year").

Comment: OOOPPSSS!!! I missed the those two (`ORDER BY` and `... = 1`).. Now it appears to be OK. Greetings!

Comment: OK thanks for the clarification. I'll take another look at this when I'm not so tired and burned out.

Comment: @Kenny83 sure. if you have further questions feel free. And if you are fine with my answer, please accept it.

Comment: @Tyron78 Sorry mate, I very much appreciate the promptness of your reply but it was too difficult for an SQL novice like me to understand. For this reason, Gordon gets the cheese :P